# Isekai manga where the main character is an extra

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I still remember that the main character is a female woman with black hair and red eyes if I am not mistaken. She saves a man who (be aware sensitive information) tries to kill himself. I have also an picture of the male lead:

[image]

Comment: @Raj As I understand the very loose criteria that are imposed on manga/manhwa/manhua questions, just the fact that the protagonist was transposed in a book/game/virtual world is enough to make this "on-topic," as is the mental time travel of "regressing."  And that's without digging into whether the story involves magic, like the laying-on-hands type healing power the female antagonist appears to have.

Comment: @DavidW Ah, I forgot what isekai meant. I will retract my close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be called [*For My Lost Love*](https://harimanga.com/manga/for-my-abandoned-love/chapter-1/comment-page-1/) or *For My Abandoned Love*/*For My Derelict Favorite*.

> I was transferred to a romance novel that I liked so much that I almost choked on the last episode. I'm a commoner, but I have a lot of money. I watched from afar as the protagonists of the original novel acquired the status of a fallen nobleman. I thought I was returning to reality after the end of the novel... Somehow after the end I got rid of the possession and lived life in the novel. As a result, I even learned behind-the-scenes stories that I didn't want to know about. My favorite protagonist, Caelus, died. While living in poverty in the novel without him, I fell ill and died. I thought I was finally returning to my reality, but I returned to the end of the novel at night. This definitely…

In the first chapter the protagonist wakes in the body of an extra named Hestia, who for no good reason, has a ton of money.  Hestia has dark hair and red eyes:

[image: Hestia looks at herself in a mirror. She has long black hair and red eyes; she's wearing a pink dress with beaded shoulder straps and a pink bow.]

[image: A side view of Hestia looking in a mirror. The voice-over reads "I fell asleep while driving after reading my favorite novel. When I opened my eyes I saw a character who wasn't mentioned even in a single line.]

[image: "Pretty," she wonders. "Who is she?" Voiceover: "Maybe it's because she was simply an extra without a role." The next frame shows Hestia standing inside the door of a room full of gold. Voiceover: "Hestia, a commoner with no family, was extremely wealthy for no reason."]

The man she saves is Kaelus, the second male lead in the novel, who kills himself in her cabin a year after she arrives.  That night she regresses and sets out to save him.

I haven't found that particular picture of him in the first few (too many) chapters, but this picture is obviously the same character:

[image: Kaelus headshot]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I just found it by accident yesterday and yes that's the manga which I was talking about :)